# Good strategy to replicate MySQL data

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump

I'm working on MySQL database, well i have a master instance and slaves, and i need to add a new slave to Master. I adopt a simple strategy to do so: Stop slave, import data to new slave, and finally start new slave.

Well i get a dump using mysqldump, and import data even i get lot of lock. Some queries have the state update, so i did not know if it is a innodb lock or input/ouput error.

Finally, i imported the hole of data, but i suspect later that the binary log was missing on master, because the rotation log was for 1 day.

My question is how to do a good replication master->slave?

Answer (score 1):

For setting a good Master- Slave Replication please visit this link [What is the Best Way to create MySQL Master-Slave Replication Setup and Troubleshoot it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-mysql-master-slave-replication-setup-and-troubles)

You can read it's a good answer.