# How to continuously keep two databases in sync

Tags: mysql

Me and a friend are developing a range of programs which uses a basic currency called "points" each user can gain and spend points for free.

The problem we face is MySQL we can connect to the databases and execute query's etc however I recently purchased a new Data Server however we would like to use more than just one server for our project incase one should go down for any reason (DDoS/DoS, Maintenance).

We have done many searches and we have encountered "MySQL Replication" (we are still reading about this) however we would like to know if there was a program or something which would keep our servers in sync (a bit like DropBox) where if a user spends 20 points on a server and the other server is down a program would have a record of the 20 points and update the other server when its back online.

I would just like some ideas if you need anything clearing up let me know, personally I would like to use just my database but he seems insistent that we use his server but sometimes his internet can really drop.

Comment: If you're not keen to go down the replication route, you could have a `updated_at` column on all your tables, and have a script push (or pull) columns that have not been seen on the secondary database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook use case for standard MySQL Replication.

You will need to decide if one DB will be the `master` and the other the `slave` in which case only the `master` replicates to the `slave`. If you want clients to be able to connect to either machine and issue writes and then have writes be propagated to both machines than you will need to look into Multi-Master replication:

http://mysql-mmm.org/

If you will be doing just standard `master` -> `slave` than MySQL has native tools as thats the default stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already answered your own question. You need to implement replication.

A quick search turned up this: [What is the Best Way to create MySQL Master-Slave Replication Setup and Troubleshoot it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-mysql-master-slave-replication-setup-and-troubles)

And in general, a search for "mysql replication" on the DBA Stackexchange is another good place to explore.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql+replication