# mysql replication and innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

Is it possible for the master (5.1) to have innodb_file_per_table = 0 and for the slave (5.1 or 5.5) to have innodb_file_per_table = 1 ?

Comment: Yes you can use `innodb_file_per_table = 1` for your slaves.

Comment: @AbdulManaf - that's good to know. I'm giving the question +1. You should write that up as an answer, preferably with some sort of reference/link.

Comment: @AbdulManaf you should make it an answer.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA  , Verace  : Added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `innodb_file_per_table = 1` for your slaves.

**Additionally take below points in your consideration**

1. If you have same version on MySQL on both Master and Slave. You can directly take backup and setup replication from Master to Slave by adding  `innodb_file_per_table = 1` on slave in `my.cnf`

   Please have a look at [**How to set Master Slave replication**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8680/4846)
2. If you have different version of MySQL , Please make sure that you are taking backup properly because different version would have mismatches in System tables (MySQL Database).

   Please have a look answer by `@RolandoMySQLDBA` for [**How to take backup properly**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2227/4846)

Comment: Thank you and thank you for your links, very useful. I will try today.

Comment: @sivann : If you found it useful you can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Yes of course I will when replication starts; the DB is several TB and took a bit longer :-)